# Function Definition Containing unit F#

Tags: function, f#

I'm new to f# programming, and I am defining a few helper functions to be used. Here are two of them:

```
    let GetPieceAt piece playerType file rank = { 
        piece = {piece = piece; playerType = playerType}  ; 
            place = { file= file; rank = rank} 
            }

    let GetPieceOnRank piece  rank playerType files () = 
        [for f in files -> GetPieceAt piece playerType f rank]
```

The first function is of the correct type: piece -> playerType -> file -> rank -> PieceAt

However, the second function has: piece -> rank -> playerType -> seq -> *unit* -> PieceAt list

Where did this unit come from? And my other function that call this are getting unit -> unit ... -> {correct return value}, and this is making errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The () in your second function definition represents an additional parameter of type unit, remove this and the function signature should be as you expect.

Comment: I thought you need the () to define a function, my bad!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`unit` in F# is represented by the empty parentheses `()` in your `GetPieceOnRank` definition.

Unlike C#, functions do not need parentheses to be called. Perhaps the placement of those parentheses was a mistake, because they are not needed and simply removing them still allows the code to compile.

```
let GetPieceOnRank piece  rank playerType files = 
    [for f in files -> GetPieceAt piece playerType f rank]
```

Answer (score 2):

Those two parentheses at the end are a value of type `unit`. Try this in interactive:

```
let a = ();;
> val a : unit = ()
```

Since you put this value in your parameter list, the compiler correctly inferred that your function has the last parameter of type `unit`.